# I would like to try and reverse this LinkedList without the use of getPreviousNode

Tags: java, loops, linked-list, reverse

By restarting Node2 at front and bringing it to one lesser index each time I thought that swap might work.
An input as J I O L 
outputs as L J I O

```
 public static void swap(Node one, Node two) {
     String temp1, temp2;
     temp1 = one.getData();
     temp2 = two.getData();
     two.setData(temp1);
     one.setData(temp2);
 }

 public static void reverse(LinkedList list) {
     int index = 0;
     Node curr1 = list.getFront();
     Node curr2= list.getFront();
     for (int i = 0; i <= list.size() / 2; i++) {
         for (int j = 0; j <= list.size() - index; j++) {
             curr2 = curr2.getNext();
             index++;
         }
         swap(curr1, curr2);
         curr1 = curr1.getNext();
     }
  }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Can't you just use java.util.Collections.reverse() method?

Answer (score 0):

This function also appears pretty complicated for what you are trying to achieve. If all you want to achieve is reversing the list use this.

`Collections.reverse(list);`

"An input as J I O L outputs as L J I O"

If you want this you could go with:

`list.add(0,list.removeLast());`

Answer (score 0):

Based on your code, you're using your own implementation of LinkedList, so I assume that, for whatever reason, you want to implement it yourself.

If so, use the following code:

```
public void ReverseLinkedList (LinkedList linkedList)
{
    LinkedListNode start = linkedList.Head;
    LinkedListNode temp = null;

    // ------------------------------------------------------------
    // Loop through until null node (next node of the latest node) is found
    // ------------------------------------------------------------

    while (start != null)
    {
        // ------------------------------------------------------------
        // Swap the “Next” and “Previous” node properties
        // ------------------------------------------------------------

        temp = start.Next;
        start.Next = start.Previous;
        start.Previous = temp;

        // ------------------------------------------------------------
        // Head property needs to point to the latest node
        // ------------------------------------------------------------

        if (start.Previous == null)
        {
            linkedList.Head = start;
        }

        // ------------------------------------------------------------
        // Move on to the next node (since we just swapped 
        // “Next” and “Previous”
        // “Next” is actually the “Previous”
        // ------------------------------------------------------------

        start = start.Previous;
    }

    // ------------------------------------------------------------
    // That's it!
    // ------------------------------------------------------------
}
```

Which I got from http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/27742/How-To-Reverse-a-Linked-List-Different-Ways  . They even show 2 other ways to solve this problem.

In every other case, I sincerely recommend you use [java.utils.Collections.reverse()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#reverse%28java.util.List%29) :)

Comment: Please stick to naming conventions, variable and method names should always begin with a lower case character. Also, if I got OP correct he didn't want to use `getPreviousNode` so I guess any usage of `node.previous` is not allowed.